# Make a one-way switch with a BJT or relay?

Tags: switches, relay, bjt, solid-state-relay

I've been trying to figure out how to make a one-way switch with some analogue electronics.

i.e.: my first idea was to use a BJT. What I'm trying to find is a design that when the base current is applied the transistor is activated and current flows connector->emitter, but then you can remove the base current and the device stays on. ("one way switch"). I can't figure out how to get that to work.

Or should I be looking at a relay for this?

Thanks!

Comment: The term you are looking for is "latching" and a latching relay would be much easier for this.

Comment: The relay often is a good solution because it is easy to work with, using a multiple-contact relay you can easily make the relay "hold" itself on. An example of a "trigger" and then "stay on" solid-state device is a **thyristor**: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thyristor You can make a "fake thyristor" using an NPN and a PNP: https://ee504cbb.files.wordpress.com/2015/01/2.gif But your "one way switch" is quite generic, you should describe **how you want to use it** because that determines what can be used. So **what** do you want to switch and **how**.

Comment: Also note that "latching relays" exist, these keep their last position without applying power. All you need is two momentary switches, one for on, one for off.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a latching circuit with only one transistor. You can make one with a thyristor and you can make a thyristor with a PNP and NPN transistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4JgRG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) A latching circuit using a thyristor. (b) The same circuit made of transistors.*

On the second circuit when ON2 is pressed Q2 receives some base current via R4 and this turns on Q2. Q1 now turns on as base current is drawn through the emitter and out through the base into Q2. Q1 then maintains Q2's base current and so the circuit latches.

Answer (score 0):

A latching circuit using an ordinary relay is very simple.

You basically wire the relay coil so it is initially energized by a momentary start switch.

Then you wire one of the relay contacts in parallel with the start switch, so they also energize the coil, even with the start switch open.  This way once the coil is energized, it stays energized - latches.

Then to unlatch, you'll need a momentary stop switch to kill the power from the contacts to the coil.

There are of course variants but that's the gist of it.

[image: latching relay circuit]